# Distribute data into groups based on existing numbers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to distribute some records to groups but I want to try to keep these groups as even as possible.
I had been looking at using ntile but I can’t work out how to take existing items into account without redoing existing records

Edit:
To give an example that should explain what I need better:

We have lots of tasks that are assigned to work groups which we want to distribute evenly across the work groups. This is a simple task for ntile..
However when these tasks are no longer required they are removed which leaves the groups having different numbers of tasks.
When new tasks are added we want to still try to keep these groups balanced.

EG Existing groups :

```
GroupName - Task Count
Group1 - 1000
Group2 - 999
Group3 - 998
```

If we were to add 6 new tasks they would have more assigned to Group 2 & 3 as they have less than group 1.

```
Task 1 - Group3
Task 2 - Group3
Task 3  -Group2
Task 4 - Group1
Task 5 - Group2
Task 6 - Group3
```

Sample tables

```
Create table GroupTable
(GroupID int, Name varchar(200) )
Insert into GroupTable values (1,'Group1')
Insert into GroupTable values (2,'Group2')
Insert into GroupTable values (3,'Group3')


Create table Jobs(jobid int identity(1,1), name varchar(100),Groupid int)
--Existing tasks
Insert into Jobs(name,Groupid) values ('Task1',1)
Insert into Jobs(name,Groupid) values ('Task2',1)
Insert into Jobs(name,Groupid) values ('Task3',1)
Insert into Jobs(name,Groupid) values ('Task4',1)
Insert into Jobs(name,Groupid) values ('Task5',2)
Insert into Jobs(name,Groupid) values ('Task6',2)
Insert into Jobs(name,Groupid) values ('Task6',2)
Insert into Jobs(name,Groupid) values ('Task7',3)

-- New tasks
Insert into Jobs(name) values ('TaskA')
Insert into Jobs(name) values ('TaskB')
Insert into Jobs(name) values ('TaskC')
Insert into Jobs(name) values ('TaskD')
Insert into Jobs(name) values ('TaskE')
Insert into Jobs(name) values ('TaskF')
```

This gives us 6 unassigned tasks and a uneven group assignment

```
GROUPNAME   TASK_COUNT
<none>      6
Group1      4
Group2      3
Group3      2
```

This means the new tasks will be assigned like this

```
TaskA - Group3
TaskB - Group3
TaskC - Group2
TaskD - Group1
TaskE - Group2
TaskF - Group3
```

Comment: Why does record 3 go into group1?  Wouldn't it go into group2 so that each group had 1000 count?

Comment: It is really hard to guess what you are trying to do specifically. What changes when a record is assigned. What do you know that records need to be assigned. A specific example of what your have tried to do would be helpful

Comment: @Dave.Gugg - that was a typo sorry

Comment: @GaryWalker - I've added a example that hopefully explains everything.